# Svg set new coordinates with animation on 2 lines simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I need a way (with CSS3 or jQuery) to change this SVG shape from `X` to `↓` (Down arrow). I tried more ways but i still have problems.

My basic idea is to get lines with id (`svg_5`, `svg_6`) and make these the head of my arrow.

```js
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if ($('.formJ').css('visibility') == 'hidden')
        $('.formJ').css('visibility', 'visible');
    else
        $('.formJ').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("a").bind({
    mouseover: function () {
        $("circle").css({ "stroke": "#80C6E7", "fill": "white" })
        $("line").css({ "stroke": "#80C6E7" })
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        $("circle").css({ "stroke": "white", "fill": "#80C6E7" })
        $("line").css({ "stroke": "white" })
    }
});

$("element").unbind('mouseover mouseout');
```

```css
body {
    background: #80C6E7;
}
a, a:active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
.wrap {
    width: 260px;
    margin: auto;
}
.formindex {
    display: none;
}
.formJ {
    visibility: hidden;
} 
.hex-icon-plus line {
    transform-origin: 100px 100px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100px 100px;
    animation: hex-icon-heart-beat 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: hex-icon-heart-beat 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

@keyframes hex-icon-heart-beat {
    0% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
    30% {
        transform: scale3d(0.90, 0.90, 1);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hex-icon-heart-beat {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.90, 0.90, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
svg {
    padding-top: 20%;
    margin: 12%;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.loginform-in {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 25px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
input {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.loginbutton {
    background: #2C3E50;
    border: 1px solid #2C3E50;   
    color: #80C6E7;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 29px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/formStyle.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="hex-icon-plus">
            <a href="Form.html">
                <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <g>
                        <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" cx="101.874999" cy="101.000003" r="97.070312" id="svg_2" />
                        <line fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" x1="100.1875" y1="40.375009" x2="100.1875" y2="160.437515" id="svg_4" />
                        <line fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" x1="41.14063" y1="100" x2="161.078126" y2="101" id="svg_5" />
                        <line fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" x1="41.14063" y1="100" x2="161.078126" y2="101" id="svg_6" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </span>
        <div class="loginform-in formJ">
            <fieldset>
                <form action="Users.html" method="get">
                    <h1>User</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="name"></label>
                            <input type="text" size="30" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="name"></label>
                            <input type="password" size="30" name="word" placeholder="Password" id="word" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" class="loginbutton" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My desired outcome is this shape

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle id="svg_2" r="97.07031" cy="101" cx="101.875" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line id="svg_4" y2="160.43751" x2="100.1875" y1="40.37501" x1="100.1875" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line id="svg_5" y2="101.0001" x2="161.07813" y1="158.55503" x1="101.11938" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line id="svg_6" y2="158.48696" x2="99.49754" y1="99.99989" x1="41.14063" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly do this with pure SVG if thats an option, not sure css/jquery is even needed.

You can morph a path, as long as they have the same number of points in the path, so this would mean a path rather than a line.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="mycross">

     <circle fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" cx="101.874999" cy="101.000003" r="97.070312" id="svg_2" />
     <path id="mypath" d="M50,100L90,100L150,100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
     <path id="vertline" d="M100,50L100,150" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
     <animate xlink:href="#mypath" attributeName="d" from="M50,100L100,100L150,100" to="M50,100L100,150L150,100" dur="2s" begin="mycross.click" fill="freeze" />

  </g>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mkpv18f/9/)

Comment: This solves my problem but i don't know how to create a new shape with paths from scratch. Do you use any editor or something else?

Comment: If its simple like above I do it by hand. If its more complex, there are programs like Inkscape, Illustrator or online svgedit that can all create svgs. Just remember though, that to morph paths, they must have the same number of points (as each point in the path is moved to its equivalent in the animation), or nothing will happen. This is a bit trickier with path drawing programs.

Comment: Is there any way to use toggle on this?

Comment: Its very fiddly to do with svg only (it maybe possible, not sure just atm). If you are ok with some js inside the svg, you could do it as follows... http://jsfiddle.net/4mkpv18f/15/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a css3 transform approach. Reversed order and not exactly the same svg, but you get the idea of using rotate and transform-origin to get the desired shape.

```css
.left, .right {
  transition:all 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.left {
  transform-origin:0% 0%;
}

.right {
  transform-origin:100% 0%;
}

svg:hover .left {
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

svg:hover .right {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <line y2="0" x2="50" y1="100" x1="50" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
    
    <line y2="50" x2="0" y1="100" x1="50" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" class="left" /> <!-- y1 from 100 to 50 -->
    
    <line y2="50" x2="100" y1="100" x1="50" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none" class="right" /> <!-- y1 from 100 to 50 -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/taneleero/pen/ZGJVyL